# How to make a persistent group in ejabbered for MUC?

Tags: c#, xmpp, ejabberd, muc

I am trying to make a persistent group in ejabbered for Multi user chat.

I am able to join a group its created by pidgen and can send message to it as well but dont know how to create a persistent group using stanza.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am trying this but its not working ..[MUC Chat Stanza](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#createroom-instant)

Comment: I am trying this but its working but when i try to list the groups or try to join that group it gives me error some times that room does not exist question is is this group a persistent group ? or just destroyed after creation? and is there any thing needed to configure a group after creation ?... ..[MUC Chat Stanza](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#createroom-instant)

Answer (score -1):

This is a standard XMPP feature. Setup the MUC as persistent from your client.